# ServiceStack.Monotouch Exception

Tags: xamarin.ios, servicestack, servicestack-text

The case of the problem is the following.
We are currently developing 2 applications for Windows Desktop and iPad version in monotouch as well. We are trying to have as much of common code as we can, but using ServiceStack.Text, while it works on the desktop app, on ipad it causes this exception.

```
"An exception was thrown by the type initializer for ServiceStack.Text.ReflectionExtensions".
```

I am trying to build the ServiceStack.Text.Monotouch Project but while i get the source from the Git it seems to be smth wrong and the project cant be build. Can any1 gimme any advice apart from using another deserializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this fork:

http://github.com/mono/ServiceStack.Text

This version is a fork based on the last available version of ServiceStack that used the MIT license and has been altered to work with the new Xamarin.iOS support for generic value type sharing (this reduces the library size, and avoids an entire class of bugs).

Comment: We never managed to get it work on a device... On simulator everything worked fine, but when we tried it on a real ipad it crashed in so many places and many times it crashed without exception. We finally used http client to perform the calls to the servicestack service and newtonsoft for deserialization.